# How to define variables in WordPress AJAX?

Tags: wp-localize-script

I have a plugin that works fine, so I was a little shocked when I turned debugging mode on the other day. The first notices are telling me that the variables in the wp_localize_script are undefined. My code is like this, below, and all the examples I've seen online have been similar. I haven't seen anything specifically defined.

```
wp_localize_script('wwww_loader', 'wwww_vars', array(
'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
'whichcats' => $whichcats,
'whichtags' => $whichtags,
'ajax_nonce' => wp_create_nonce('ww-ww-ww'), ));
```

So, it's the 'whichcats' and 'whichtags'. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

The AJAX works and the correct information is passed through the AJAX. When I DEBUG it shows "notices" for those variables inside wp_localize_script. So, the only reason I think anything is wrong is because of the Debug notice, such as this...

> NOTICE: wp-content/plugins/ww-ww-ww/ww-ww-ww.php:212 - Undefined variable: whichcats
>   require_once('wp-admin/admin-header.php'), do_action('admin_enqueue_scripts'), call_user_func_array, wwww_load_all_admin_scripts

The jquery looks like this (and works)...

```
$(".wwww_catselect").submit(function(e) {
    // Serialize the form data
    var wwww_checkboxdata = $(this).serialize();

    var data = {
        action : "wwww_select_cats",
        whichcats : wwww_checkboxdata,
        security : wwww_vars.ajax_nonce,
    };

    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        $('#wwww_ajax_lists').html(response);
    });
    return false;
});
```

It behaves exactly the way it should, so should I just ignore the notices? Or is there a way to fix the code so that the notices in debug are not there any more?

Comment: where do you set `$whichcats` and `$whichtags`?

Comment: You mean in the jquery? I've ammended the question.

Comment: the notice refers to your php function `wwww_load_all_admin_scripts`, you use an undefined php variable inside that function.

Comment: Right! It's saying it's the "whichcats" inside the wp_localize_script. So my question is, how do I define it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean when you access you variables in JS code just by name they are really undefined in JavaScript environment. In order to access variables in JS you need to type  as in your example
`www_vars.whichcats`
instead of just `whichcats`

Also it's good to understand how wp_localize_script  works.

First param is your js file handle previously declared with `wp_enquee_script` or `wp_register_script` (in your case it is `wwww_loader`). It says when it should be fired, because you really need these data for certain js file only, when it's plugged in to particular page.

Second parameter is name of global variable which will store all your data passed in to JS via third argument - associative array of data.

It will create inline JS script when your script from handle will be included. And this inline JS will initialize these data in variable with name you've passed in as second parameter.

So first check if you've specified right script  handle in first param. And check if you've queued this script before. 
For example:

`wp_enqueue_script( 
       'wwww_loader', 
       plugins_url( '/js/wwww_loader.js', __FILE__ ),
       array( 'jquery' ) 
);`
Then you can add needed data to it's js  execution context.

`wp_localize_script('wwww_loader', 'wwww_vars', array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'whichcats' => $whichcats,
        'whichtags' => $whichtags,
        'ajax_nonce' => wp_create_nonce('ww-ww-ww'), )
);`

And finally you can check if you've really passed these data to JS
in a browser for example in Chrome open developer console hit F12 and in console type your variable name `wwww_vars` and press enter. If your script was properly linked  you'll see them as object in developer console output, otherwise it'll show you `undefined`
If it'll show you it's value all is ok and you can reference in your JS file to these data like
`wwww_vars.whichtags`

EDIT:
Looks like you pass $whichtags and $whichcats variables to function but they are not previously defined in PHP. If so just initialize them before calling `wp_localize_script` with some default value, 0 or false or array() or '' emtpy string which one will describe your data in future when they'll be filled in just before wp_localize script for example:

`$whichtags=''; 
$whichcats='';
wp_localize_script('wwww_loader', 'wwww_vars', array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'whichcats' => $whichcats,
        'whichtags' => $whichtags,
        'ajax_nonce' => wp_create_nonce('ww-ww-ww'), )
);`

Comment: Thanks very much for the full answer... I am enqueueing the script and it works. I've edited the question to explain.

Comment: Looks like you pass $whichtags and $whichcats variables to function but they are not previously defined in PHP. If so just initialize them before calling wp_localize_script with some default value, 0 or false or array() or '' emtpy string  which one will describe your data in future when they'll be filled in. just before wp_localize script $whichtags=''; $whichcats=''; for example